# Get value of the textarea when the mouse is not inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do this:

I have a textarea with some text and the mouse is "on" in the textarea. When I take away the mouse from the textarea, I would like to get the text that has been written in a  `<span>` or `<p>`.

Is there a function to get the information when the mouse is not in the textarea?

Comment: Well, there's no built-in or JavaScript / jQuery function. But you can surely code it. `:)`

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question, a textarea can't have span or p elements.

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged the question with jQuery, I assume you have jQuery present. Then, you can do

```
$('textarea').mouseleave(function () {
  $('span').html($(this).val())
})
```

if your HTML looks like

```
<textarea></textarea>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can take the .mouseleave() method.

For the full information go visit [the jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) of that function.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
$(function () {
  $(".theArea").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).prop("contenteditable", true);
  }).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).prop("contenteditable", false);
  });
});
```

```css
.theArea {border: 1px solid #999; padding: 5px;}
.theArea[contenteditable="true"] {background: #ddf;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="theArea">Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept.

However, you aren’t invisible. Going incognito doesn’t hide your browsing from your employer, your internet service provider, or the websites you visit.</div>
```